# Removing double quotes while rendering html on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult ReadConfig()
{
    IEnumerable<string> text = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\nys\source\repos\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Configs\Json_test.txt");
    IEnumerator<string> en = text.GetEnumerator();
    var X = @"<p>";
    List<string> T = new List<string>();
    while (en.MoveNext())
    {
        X += en.Current;

        T.Add(en.Current);
        T.Add("\n");
    }
    X += "</p>";
    var dat = new data { context = X };
    ViewBag.context = T;

    return View(dat);
}
```

So, the code here is supposed to read from a file and spit it out as text in the html page.

```
@model WebApplication4.Models.data
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReadConfig";
}

<h2>ReadConfig</h2>
<div>
    @foreach(string a in ViewBag.context)
    {
        @Html.Raw(a)
        <br />
    }
</div>
```

The html does not print out the formatted text but I see the text within double quotes.

How do I preserve the spacings and format of the text from the text file and simply spit it out to the html file??

Comment: Use `Pre` tag which preserves both spaces and line breaks

Answer (score 0):

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath(your text file path);
string content = string.Empty;

using (var stream = new StreamReader(filepath)) {
  content = stream.ReadToEnd();
}

ViewBag.context = content;
```

try this